# ignore the characters contained in the database value in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

For example, I have a database table as follows :

[image]

I want to show lname value in html but by eliminating the " Mr. " without changing the values ​​contained in the database . is there any way to do this using a php script ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
echo preg_replace('/(mr\.\s+|ms.\s+)(.*)/ui', '$2', 'Mr. Bean');

// Mr. Bean -> Bean
// Bean -> Bean
// Ms. Stone -> Stone
// Jack Bean -> Jack Bean
```

Comment: Can you explain the function : \ s + ) ( . * ) / ui ' , ' $ 2 'on your script ? Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: `\.` is escaped dot. `\s+` is separator one or more times (`+`). `|` is selection one of from represented expressions. `.*` is any symbol 0 or more times (`*`). `u` is unicode support. `i` is no sensetive to upper/lower case. `$2` is expression in second `()` - all after mr. or ms. in this case.

Comment: btw how about preg_replace used for path / directory ? for example, eliminating the " ../ " ? such as : ../images/upload

Answer (score 1):

You can Do it with the Explode Function.Try it Below Code. `$name= "place your lname"`

```
<?php
$name  = "Mr. Smith";
$split = explode(" ", $name);
echo $split[1]; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show there are more ways to skin a cat...

```
$name  = "Mr. Smith";
$user = strstr($name, 'Mr. ', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints Smith
```